# Datetime.parseexact throws error

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, date, datetime

I have below code

inputdatetime value is `"2014/09/11 8:06 AM"`
dateformat is `"yyyy/MM/dd h:mm a"`

```
CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

string dateforamat = string.Concat(date, " ", time);

returnValue = DateTime.ParseExact(inputDateTime, dateforamat, culture);
```

I am getting format exception

Comment: Note that raw slash (`/`) characters in date format strings actually stand for the [date separator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dateSeparator), which varies depending on the culture you specify. I would advise surrounding slashes with single quotes (`yyyy'/'MM'/'dd`) to avoid surprises in the long run.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: you can prevent that with `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` which OP already did.

Comment: @Tim, had the questioner passed `InvariantCulture` directly, as you did in your answer, I would not have said anything. However, storing it in a local variable makes me think that it could possibly be modified before the call to `ParseExact()`, either now or in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Use `tt` instead of `a`

```
DateTime.ParseExact("2014/09/11 8:06 AM", "yyyy/MM/dd h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Read: [The "tt" Custom Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#ttSpecifier)